# How to convert a string to integer entered in input functon?

Tags: python, input

```
number=input('Enter a number? ')
print(number)
```

I want to convert this in single statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you can use `int()`:

```
number=int(input('Enter a number? '))
print(number)
```

Otherwise, to be fool-proof, use try..except:

```
while True:
  try: 
    number=int(input("Enter a number ? "))
    break
  except ValueError:
    print("Please input a vaild number !!")
```